# How to do deep traversals with FindItem queries

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I am sending the following XML query to EWS using the `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` method. It works as long as Traversal is set to "Shallow".  I get a "The request is invalid" error when I set Traversal to "Deep". 
 How do I recursively search subfolders if I can't do deep searches?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Header> 
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" /> 
    </soap:Header> 
    <soap:Body> 
      <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow"> 
        <m:ItemShape> 
          <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape> 
        </m:ItemShape> 
        <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" /> 
        <m:Restriction> 
          <t:Contains ContainmentMode="FullString" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase"> 
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories" /> 
            <t:Constant Value="MyCategory" /> 
          </t:Contains> 
        </m:Restriction> 
        <m:ParentFolderIds> 
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" /> 
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" /> 
        </m:ParentFolderIds> 
      </m:FindItem> 
    </soap:Body> 
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sorry but deep searches in the inbox do NOT work with FindFolder. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findfolder-operation ...
Remarks FindFolder returns only the first 512 bytes of any streamable property. For Unicode, it returns the first 255 characters by using a null-terminated Unicode string. **Deep traversal queries cannot be performed on public folders.**
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FindItem EWS call does not support Traversal="Deep". See [FindItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579422(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_ExampleEWSMA).

This is because the call will search for items in the folders specified in ParentFolderIds. In order to do a recursive search, you will need to get the list of folders to include in the search by using the FindFolder EWS Operation which supports Traversal="Deep" on non public folders. See [FindFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563918(v=exchg.150).aspx) for additional documentation.